# Grails generate war size less than 55MB

Tags: grails, war

I'm using GRAILS(2.5.0),as I create a new project and generate WAR.

Size is 55MB.

Can I make it lighter?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to build war using this command: *grails war -nojars*
It will build a war without WEB-INF/lib jars. But you have to provide them to your webserver before deployment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grails war -nojars`

reference: [create-much-smaller-grails-war-file](http://mrhaki.blogspot.mx/2009/05/create-much-smaller-grails-war-file.html)